# Is there a single app that allows for quick searching, viewing, and editing of text files?

Tags: software-recommendation, sync, android, text-editor, notes

I have a large (thousands) collection of notes stored on my drive as text files and synced to my other computers via UbuntuOne.  Currently I use grep to search for the file I want, nautilus to open it, and gedit to edit it.  Is there a single app I can use that will allow me to do all three at once?

I used to use Evernote, but their text editors are so crappy I had to dump it.  I also used Tomboy for a long time, but the lack of a web based editor and no Android based editor either was a showstopper.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about the gedit file search plugin?

Found it here: http://live.gnome.org/Gedit/Plugins

**Gedit File Search**: Search for a string in all files in a directory and its subdirectories.

- Project Page: http://oliver.github.com/gedit-file-search/.
- A gedit 3 version is available on a separate branch: see https://github.com/oliver/gedit-file-search/issues/13 and https://github.com/adam-yorba/gedit-file-search/tree/gedit-3

[image]

You already use gedit and now have no need for grep and nautilus ;)

Answer (score 0):

I use CherryTree, Ubuntu 12.04 has this aplication in the repositories.
From my point of view is a great application for managing hundreds of notes.

Comment: Never heard of this application before.  After installing it I can say, that while it looks nice, it has all the same limitations as Tomboy -- a proprietary file format (not plain text or rtf).  Thus there is no web or android editing capability.  Thanks anyway.